TypeError on Dart callback function with children class as parameter and return
I'm encountering a TypeError with the message:
Type '(Job) => ListTile' is not a subtype of type '(Model) => Widget'

in my Flutter app when trying to build a widget by passing a callback. The callback type is defined as:
final Widget Function(T) listItemBuilder;

in a class:
class ListPageBuilder<T extends Model> extends StatefulWidget

In the calling code, I instantiated ListPageBuilder with:
ListPageBuilder(
  listItemBuilder: (Job item) {
    return ListTile(
      key: Key(item.pk!),
      title: Text(item.title),
      subtitle: Text(item.description),
    );
  },
);

where Job inherits from Model. I expected this to work since Job is a subclass of Model, and ListTile is a Widget.
Here is full code
ListPageBuilder implementation

class ListPageBuilder<T extends Model> extends StatefulWidget {
  final bool canView;
  final bool canAdd;
  final String modelVerboseName;
  final Repository repository;
  final void Function()? onItemTap;
  final Widget Function(T) listItemBuilder;

  const ListPageBuilder({
    super.key,
    required this.modelVerboseName,
    required this.canView,
    required this.canAdd,
    required this.repository,
    required this.listItemBuilder,
    this.onItemTap,
  });
  @override
  State<ListPageBuilder> createState() => _ListPageBuilderState();
}

class _ListPageBuilderState extends State<ListPageBuilder> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchItems();
  }

  var items = [];
  int? nextPage = 1;
  bool _isLoading = true;
  final _scrollController = ScrollController();
  final _searchController = TextEditingController();

  String? getSearchTerm() {
    return _searchController.text.length >= 3 ? _searchController.text : null;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> getFilters() {
    var filters = <String, dynamic>{"page": nextPage};
    var searchTerm = getSearchTerm();
    if (searchTerm != null) {
      filters["search"] = searchTerm;
    }
    return filters;
  }

  void fetchItems() async {
    if (nextPage == null) return;
    try {
      var response = await widget.repository.list(getFilters());
      var items = response.results;
      nextPage = response.next != null ? getPage(response.next!) : null;

      _isLoading = false;
      setState(() {
        this.items.addAll(items);
      });
    } on HttpException catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _scrollController.addListener(() {
      var nextPageTriggerLimit =
          0.75 * _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent;

      if (_scrollController.position.pixels > nextPageTriggerLimit &&
          !_isLoading) {
        _isLoading = true;
        fetchItems();
      }
    });

    return Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: const AppNavigationBar(),
      floatingActionButton: widget.canAdd
          ? FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/customers/create");
              },
              child: const Icon(Icons.add),
            )
          : null,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
            child: widget.canView
                ? Column(
                    children: [
                      TextFormField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          hintText: "Rechercher un ${widget.modelVerboseName}",
                          suffixIcon: const Icon(Icons.search),
                        ),
                        controller: _searchController,
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          if (value.isEmpty || value.length >= 3) {
                            setState(() {
                              items = [];
                              nextPage = 1;
                              fetchItems();
                            });
                          }
                        },
                      ),
                      (items.isEmpty && _isLoading)
                          ? const SizedBox(
                              width: 50,
                              height: 50,
                              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                            )
                          : Expanded(
                              child: ListView.separated(
                                controller: _scrollController,
                                itemCount: items.length,
                                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                  var item = items[index];
                                  return widget.listItemBuilder(item);
                                },
                                separatorBuilder: (context, index) =>
                                    const Divider(),
                              ),
                            )
                    ],
                  )
                : const Center(
                    child: Text(
                      "Vous n'avez pas la permission de consulter cette page",
                    ),
                  ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


and calling code is
class JobListPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const JobListPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListPageBuilder<Job>(
      canView: true,
      canAdd: true,
      repository: jobRepository,
      modelVerboseName: "job",
      listItemBuilder: (Job item) {
        return ListTile(
          key: Key(item.pk!),
          title: Text(item.title),
          subtitle: Text(item.description),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}


How can I resolve this issue?

It'll help if [edit] your question to make the code fully runnable.

@MendelG it's done

Are you sure you're getting that error with this code?  The error indicates that you're using ListPageBuilder with its default type argument, but in the code you've shown, you're explicitly specifying ListPageBuilder<Job> (and the type parameter should be inferred from the listItemBuilder callback that explicitly takes a Job parameter).

Is Job inheriting from the same Model class as ListPageBuilder or is it possible you are importing two different Model classes from different libraries?

yes, I'm sure that it's that code giving me the error. And Job inherits from same Model class as ListPageBuilder.

@mmcdon20 The Type '(Job) => ListTile' is not a subtype of type '(Model) => Widget' error would be a valid error if using ListPageBuilder with no explicit type argument (and if the type argument could not be inferred).  A function that takes a Job argument is not substitutable for a function that could take any Model argument.

The issue I see here is that, while ListPageBuilder has a generic type definition, the underlying state class _ListPageBuilderState  does not. The items variable in the state class has a type of dynamic since you neither explicitly provide an initial list nor specify a type. I suspect the issue will be resolved once you correctly define a generic type on the state class and data list variable.
To resolve the issue, set the explicit type of the items variable to T of the state class with generic <T extends Model>:

///...

class ListPageBuilder<T extends Model> extends StatefulWidget {
  const ListPageBuilder({
    super.key,
    ///...
    required this.listItemBuilder,
  });

  final Widget Function(T) listItemBuilder;
  ///...

  @override
  State<ListPageBuilder<T>> createState() => _ListPageBuilderState<T>();
}

class _ListPageBuilderState<T extends Model> extends State<ListPageBuilder<T>> {
  ///...

  final items = <T>[];
  
  ///...
}



I'm able to make it works by writing
class JobListPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const JobListPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListPageBuilder<Job>(
      canView: true,
      canAdd: true,
      repository: jobRepository,
      modelVerboseName: "job",
      listItemBuilder: (Model item) {
        Job job = item as Job;
        return ListTile(
          key: Key(job.pk!),
          title: Text(job.title),
          subtitle: Text(job.description),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

It is not clean but it works and I'm still looking for and better solution.
